# Does Javascript 'Object.defineProperty' only accept prototype object as parameter

Tags: javascript, object, properties, prototype

From ObjectConstructor.defineProperty I see the first parameter of this function is (o:any), which indicates any object.

So I tried to define a property for both constructor function and instance, like below:

```
function h(){this.a='abc';}
h()
console.log(exports.a);
Object.defineProperty(h,'b');//TypeError
var hinst=new h();
Object.defineProperty(hinst,'b');//TypeError
Object.def
```

Actually, both Object.defineProperty statements will throw runtime exception, saying

> TypeError: Property description must be an object: undefined.
>   Why this error happen, any indications, or any de factor restrictions about how Object.defineProperty should be used?

Comment: [Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548687(v=vs.94).aspx)

Comment: "*I see the first parameter of this function …*" - what documentation are you reading? What does it say about the second parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Object.defineProperty() method defines a new property directly on
>   an object, or modifies an existing property on an object, and returns
>   the object. [More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

The correct Syntax is:

`Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor)`

Your script instead miss the `descriptor`, example from your code:

`Object.defineProperty(h,'b');`

Below a sample of how should be used instead:

```js
function h() {
  this.a = 'abc';
}
Object.defineProperty(h, 'b',{
  value: 37,
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
var hinst = new h();
Object.defineProperty(hinst, 'b',{
  value: 37,
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
console.log(hinst);
```